# neo4j docker coreos - logging everything to the console

Tags: docker, coreos, neo4j

I’m setting up neo4j in docker for use in a coreos cluster. The container is running `neo4j console` and I want *all* the logging to go to the console.

I’ve updated `logging.properties` to only use the console logger and have set the level to `FINEST`.

I assume there is some logging of queries and database engine execution, but I'm not seeing any additional logging even when exercising the database a bit.

I want to get *all* the logging going to the console so I can use systemd journaling to handle it from there.

So, is removing the fileHandler from the logging.properties enough? Have I missed some important source of logs?